# How to make a light affect a single object in a scene?

Tags: lighting

I want to light a single object in a scene. It has many purposes for my render. How do I go about it?

Comment: I think you need to use the Compositor and the View Layers

Comment: Ins't there a way to do it in 3d viewport itself as it will be quite a task if i have to render and re-render everytime. Also, i do not even know the way as you mentioned just now... lol

Comment: maybe you can cheat: bake the texture and use an Emission node instead of a Diffuse, so that the object will appear enlighted

Comment: Well, can you tell me the 1st way? Using compositor and view layers?

Comment: the second way would not work in your case?

Comment: I have never baked a texture. Plus whatever little i know I need to be able to at least view it in 3d-Viewport. Because I have to experiment a lot with lights and a single pass never suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the object and its light in a collection:

[image]

Create a second view layer in the *Outliner*:

[image]

In *View Layer 1* enable the collections except the one with the object and light:

[image]

In *View Layer 2* enable the collection with the object and light only:

[image]

Enable the *Film > Transparent* option:

[image]

Render, then go into the *Compositor* window, enable *Use Nodes* and *Backdrop* (in order to see the render in the background, press <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to zoom or unzoom, or select the *Viewer* node and catch the handles of the image), duplicate the *Render Layers* node, in each one select a render layer, mix them with a *Color > Alpha Over*, plug into an *Output > Composite* and an *Output > Viewer*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works for my objective. :)